# How to display the date one day ahead?

Tags: django

Well, currently I only display the 'calendar' with the current date. I would like the current date to be displayed in one field, and the next date to be displayed in the next one, up to 5 days later.

```
def Schedule(request):
    date = datetime.date.today()
    report=Submissions.objects.filter(execution_date=date)
    

    context={
        'date':date,
        'report':report,
    }
    return render(request, 'staff/work_schedule.html', context)




<div class="row no-gutters" style="width: 100%;">
    <div style="width: 100%;background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);color: white;font-weight: 800;font-size: 12px;">{{date}}</div>
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
        <tbody>
            {% for qs in report %}
            <tr style="font-size: 10px;text-align: center;">
                <th style="width: 8%;">{{qs.client.user.get_full_name}}, tel.:{{qs.client.phone_number}}</th>
                <th style="width: 8%;">{{qs.client.post_code}} {{qs.client.city}}, ul.{{qs.client.street}}</th>
                <th style="width: 40%;">{{qs.contents|linebreaks|truncatewords_html:50}}</th>
                <th style="width: 40%;">{{qs.details_planned_service|linebreaks|truncatewords_html:50}}</th>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div style="width: 100%;background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);color: white;font-weight: 800;font-size: 12px;">29 styczeń 2024</div>
    <div style="width: 100%;background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);color: white;font-weight: 800;font-size: 12px;">30 styczeń 2024</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add another variable next_date to your context and then use in the template.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def Schedule(request):
  date = datetime.date.today()
  report=Submissions.objects.filter(execution_date=date)


  context={
      'date':date,
      'report':report,
      'next_date': date + timedelta(days=1), # set the number of days
  }
  return render(request, 'staff/work_schedule.html', context)
```

Comment: Can you tell me how to compare the current date with the date in the report? Aligning the date variable (i.e. today's) with the report date works, but next_date does not display anything. It does not work ` {{for qs in report}}{% if next_date == qs.execution_date %} NEXT_CODE... `, but when I give the date variable, the data is displayed correctly.

Comment: First check if your `next_date` variable is correct. Then converting the dates to their string formats and then compare the strings using template filters.

{% if next_date|date:'Y-m-d'' == qs.execution_date|date:'Y-m-d' %}

Comment: I did something like this and it works exactly as I wanted                                              ' date = datetime.date.today() ext_date1=date+timedelta(days=1)
    next_date2=date+timedelta(days=2))    report=Submissions.objects.filter(Q(execution_date=date) | Q(execution_date=next_date1) | Q(execution_date=next_date2))
context={ 'date':date,  'report':report, 'next_date1':next_date1,'next_date2':next_date2
 }